# Can you use a tkinter and/or virtual display with Heroku?

Tags: heroku, python

I am developing a Python app, using Django to create the website to access my scripts. The scripts open a tkinter window and I use PIL to take a screenshot. Then the screenshot is sent as an image to the client. This works locally, but of course web servers don't generally have displays, so it does not work out of the box on Heroku. I got it working on my own server using Xvfb (by running the Python script, not using a web server). I have searched high and low and cannot find a definitive answer as to whether tkinter and Xvfb or some other virtual display is possible in Heroku.

**Update**: I tried using *apt buildpack* as suggested below, created **Aptfile** with the following contents:

```
xvfb
python-tk
python3-tk
tk-dev
python3-venv
```

Everything installs smoothly (as in it appears that I set it up correctly and it seems to be installing all of those things), but when I try to load a page that uses tk, I am still getting `No module named '_tkinter'`, which is exactly what it was doing before I tried this. I also tried several variations of this fil, and none solved the problem. So no progress so far. Any insight from others who have done this successfully?

I should note that I know that it still won't fully work since I haven't done anything with the virtual display yet, but I am hoping to get past the missing `_tkinter` and then see what error occurs next (i.e. no display found or whatever it will say next).

So my main question: **Can someone give me a definitive and informed answer about whether or not it is possible to get tkinter to work on Heroku?** Please do not respond with "tkinter will not work on a web server" unless you can back up that claim. As I mentioned above, I have been able to do this on my own headless server (not when called through a web server yet, but I am relatively certain that if I took the time I could do so eventually--but I am hoping it won't come to that), so it is possible to do it. I just don't know if it is possible specifically with Herokuo. I also know people used to do it 7-9 years ago, but I cannot find any definitive answers within the past few years.

Comment: How is your Heroku application built? Are you using Docker or one or more buildpacks? Either way, there should be a route to try it out by installing the required packages with `apt`.

Comment: I'm using the Python buildpack. I don't think it's as simple as using apt--I don't even know how to use apt since I don't know how to even access the server directly.  It seems like it might be easier to figure out how to set up my own web server than make Heroku work since there seems to be a lot of hoops to jump through (how to install Tk/Tcl, tkinter, Xvfb, how to start Xvfb, etc.).

Comment: There is an [apt buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) you can try, which will use `apt` to install packages into your application's slug. That's certainly not a complete solution to your question, but at least it's a start you can use to experiment.

Comment: @DavidReed I tried what you suggested, but as mentioned above in my edited post, I still get `No module named '_tkinter'` error.